# Calling a .net webservice from a plain HTML site using jQuery

Tags: .net, jquery, web-services

I wanted to know it is possible to call a hosted .net web service from a HTML page using jQuery? I tried this piece of code, but it doesn't work for me:

```
 $('#myForm').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: '{}',
            url: "http://localhost:49590/Service.asmx?op=HelloWorld",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success:
                function(response) {                   
                    alert(response.d);
                },
            failure:
                function(result) {
                    alert(result.status + ' ' + result.statusText);
                }
        });
    });
```

And the webservice is as such:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class Service : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    [WebMethod]
    public string HelloWorld()
    {
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

I have searched for this and found only examples where it is done from asp.net or asp.net mvc projects. I am not sure what I am missing but I thought this was possible from a plain HTML site with javascript, so can someone please point me in the right direction.

Cheers!

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean?

Comment: Please provide details as to what you mean by " it doesn't work for me"

Comment: What i mean it doesn't work is, when I step over the js with firebug, it just goes straight past the success and failure functions. Hence nothing happens at all. I am thinking there is something fundamentally wrong with my code. 

But before all that, I need to know if this concept works, i.e. HTML page, jQuery and a .NET webservice.

Comment: It should work, it doesn't matter if its plain site or not (anyway all pages are fundamentally static as HTTP stateless), so my first suspect will be a syntax error on your jQuery.

Comment: Is it the datatype? I have it set as JSON in jQuery code, but is there somewhere where i need to specify this in the .net webservice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you just have some syntax errors. I created the following classic web service:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class HelloWorld : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    [WebMethod]
    public string Hello(string name)
    {
        return "Hello " + name;
    }
}
```

And the following HTML page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Calling Classic Web Services with jQuery</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function () {
        $("a#SayHello").click(function (e) {
          e.preventDefault();

          $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data: '{"name": "' + $("input#name").val() + '"}',
            url: 'http://localhost:7663/HelloWorld.asmx/Hello',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            success:
              function (data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
                alert(data.d);
              },
            error:
              function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(textStatus);
              }
          });
        });
      });    
    </script>
</head>
<body>
  <input id="name" /><a id="SayHello" href="#">Greetings!</a>  
</body>
</html>
```

And was able to produce a valid response.

Hope that helps!

EDIT: Here is how I created the web service in Visual Studio 2010.  Note that I changed my framework to 3.5, though 2.0 and 3.0 offer the same project.  4 does not.

[image: Classic Web Service in Visual Studio 2010]

The web config might look a little bare if you're not using VS2010, but know I didn't touch it at all:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.extensions" type="System.Web.Configuration.SystemWebExtensionsSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
        <sectionGroup name="scripting" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
            <section name="scriptResourceHandler" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingScriptResourceHandlerSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
            <sectionGroup name="webServices" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingWebServicesSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
                <section name="jsonSerialization" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingJsonSerializationSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="Everywhere"/>
                <section name="profileService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingProfileServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
                <section name="authenticationService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingAuthenticationServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
                <section name="roleService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingRoleServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/></sectionGroup></sectionGroup></sectionGroup></configSections><appSettings/>
<connectionStrings/>
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true">
        <assemblies>
            <add assembly="System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
            <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add assembly="System.Xml.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
            <add assembly="System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/></assemblies></compilation>
    <!--
  The <authentication> section enables configuration 
  of the security authentication mode used by 
  ASP.NET to identify an incoming user. 
-->
    <authentication mode="Windows"/>
    <!--
   The <customErrors> section enables configuration 
   of what to do if/when an unhandled error occurs 
   during the execution of a request. Specifically, 
   it enables developers to configure html error pages 
   to be displayed in place of a error stack trace.

   <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="GenericErrorPage.htm">
     <error statusCode="403" redirect="NoAccess.htm" />
     <error statusCode="404" redirect="FileNotFound.htm" />
   </customErrors>
-->
    <pages>
        <controls>
            <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/></controls></pages>
    <httpHandlers>
        <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx"/>
        <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/></httpHandlers>
    <httpModules>
        <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/></httpModules></system.web>
<system.codedom>
        <compilers>
            <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" warningLevel="4">
                <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v3.5"/>
                <providerOption name="WarnAsError" value="false"/></compiler></compilers></system.codedom>
<system.webServer>
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <modules>
        <remove name="ScriptModule"/>
        <add name="ScriptModule" preCondition="managedHandler" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/></modules>
    <handlers>
        <remove name="WebServiceHandlerFactory-Integrated"/>
        <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactory"/>
        <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices"/>
        <remove name="ScriptResource"/>
        <add name="ScriptHandlerFactory" verb="*" path="*.asmx" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add name="ScriptResource" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/></handlers></system.webServer>
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" appliesTo="v2.0.50727">
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="3.5.0.0"/></dependentAssembly>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions.Design" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="3.5.0.0"/></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding></runtime></configuration>
```

Comment: I tried your code, but I am getting data is null on the return.

Comment: Can you please show me what the web.config looks like? I added a WCF project then removed the default service and added a plain web service. Is this what you did?

Comment: I added a picture and the web.config. We're not dealing with a WCF service, rather a classic ASMX web service. If you'd rather create a WCF service and call it using AJAX, that too is possible but if you don't need all of the flexibility of WCF, ASMX is fine.

Comment: Thanks for all that. I really appreciate it. I did as you told (and I am using VS2010). It's returning back with a textStatus of "Success", but I am getting null for the data.d.

Comment: I'd recommend downloading Fiddler2 (or the HTTP traffic analyzer of your choice -- Firebug will even suffice) and looking at both the request and response. Make sure the request is getting there in entirety.

Comment: I got this finally working, but only when I had the html page inside the webservice project. As soon as I took it out of the project, it did not work. No idea why this is the case.

Comment: Can you elaborate? Are you using a fully qualified url in the $.ajax call?