# How to access the web service in html page? Static site?

Tags: web-services

Accessing web service in HTML pages, i have a static site i want to access one web service in that site.

Comment: What type of web service? REST? SOAP? Is the HTML page going to be in the same domain (same server/address) of the webservices?

Comment: Check here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2741435/calling-a-net-webservice-from-a-plain-html-site-using-jquery

same question already got answered

Comment: you may elaborate further your use case

Answer (score 4):

If you are running a static site I assume that the webservice you want to access is *not on the same domain* and you *cannot set up a proxy* on the server side. If both assumptions are correct you cannot use "ordinary" ajax because of the same origin policy in the browser. Your best bet may be [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) as it is supported by many webservices.

I will give you a simple example. To retrieve a value stored under the key "mykey" from the [openkeyval](http://openkeyval.org/) storage webservice in JavaScript with jQuery, call

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://api.openkeyval.org/mykey",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function(data){
        // do something with data
    }
});
```

and to store a value, call

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://api.openkeyval.org/store/",
    data: "mykey=myvalue",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function(data){
        // your value has been succesfully saved
    }
});
```

Please note that nowadays many people consider [Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) a better alternative to JSONP. However, it may be a bit harder to get started for you.

Answer (score 1):

Try Javascript, here is sample code

```
 <html>
  <head>
   <title>Hello World</title>
    <script language="JavaScript">
     function InitializeService(){
      service.useService(http://localhost/MyWebService.asmx?wsdl, "HelloWorldService");
      service.HelloWorldService.callService("HelloWorld");
     }
     function ShowResult(){
      alert(event.result.value);
     }
    </script>
   </head>
  <body onload="InitializeService()" id="service" 
        onresult="ShowResult()"> </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: service is not a standard javascript object and you probably need to be your url between string delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the answer provided by benedolph, but thought I might add ideas that go against his assumptions.

These steps may be more complex than you'd like, but really not terribly complicated - and would be cheap, if not free. But set aside at least one full day...

1) If you don't have one, get a domain to proxy the multiple services. Either free or as little as 5 USD per month (depending on your needs).

2) Write your proxy. This can be done in the language of your choice - Java (recommend Play framework), PHP (recommend CodeIgniter framework), Javascript (Node), Ruby (Rails), etc. What you'll do (from a high level) might look like:

```
- Read request. This would be a url you configure on the server app. 
  The url might look something like,  "http://yourdomain.net/get/mashup/{service1:yourfirstservice.com, service2:yournextservice.com,...}. 

- Parse the json into individual requests and load each of them from your server app. (The fastest way that I've found to complete this task is by using cURL's multi_init and multi_exec functions, via PHP. That said, Java and Ruby have equally powerful multi-threading capabilities).

- Put the results of each query into a json map.

- Once all responses come back, output the json response from your server and consume on your client side.
```

Anyway, that's what I'd do. Hope my response helps in one way or another!

-Brandon

Comment: +1 for the clean way to do it. Also, caching of frequent requests would be possible this way. Just to add another server side option: Python with the [web2py](http://web2py.com) framework is an easy option for beginners. There is a nice [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M5IPlMe83yI&noredirect=1) on how to consume a webservice with web2py including caching. Free hosting for basic use with one-click installation is available on [pythonanywhere](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Jquery but the web service that you are accessing must reside on the same domain as the jQuery script that is making the request.It must comply the same domain policy.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#Save').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "mydomain.com/test/ws/getData",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: "{BizName:'" + BizName + "'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function(msg) {
                $('#status').html('Id: '+msg['d']['Id']);
            },
            error: function(e) {
                $('#status').innerHTML = "Unavailable";
            }
        });
    });
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Its so possible but you'll need some jquery, javascript, ajax for it